# PineScript - Why EMAs calculated from chart vs request.security function don't give the same value?

Tags: pine-script, moving-average

See the following code, if you select in Tradingview SPY as the chart ticker.
The values for the EMA(200) calculated with the security function vs the ones calculated with with the CLOSE variable from the chart are different.
I've tried to change this through the max_bars_back parameter, but this parameter seems not to affect the request.security behaviour.

Today I have these results:

```
Ema Sec1 = $417.848
Ema Sec2 = $417.848
Ema Chart = $415.278 <=== different, and I guess the correct one!

//@version=5
indicator("EMA not working")

// select SPY as the ticker for the chart.

[price,ema_security1]= request.security("SPY","D",[close,ta.ema(close,200)])
ema_security2 = ta.ema(price,200)
ema_chart = ta.ema(close,200)

var table _table = table.new(position.bottom_right, 4 , 4 ) 
table.cell(_table, 0, 0, "EMA Sec1", text_size="huge",bgcolor=color.orange)
table.cell(_table, 0, 1, str.tostring(ema_security1, '#.###'), text_size="huge", bgcolor=color.yellow)
table.cell(_table, 1, 0, "EMA Sec2", text_size="huge",bgcolor=color.orange)
table.cell(_table, 1, 1, str.tostring(ema_security2, '#.###'), text_size="huge", bgcolor=color.yellow)
table.cell(_table, 2, 0, "EMA Chart", text_size="huge",bgcolor=color.orange)
table.cell(_table, 2, 1, str.tostring(ema_chart, '#.###'), text_size="huge", bgcolor=color.yellow)
```

Comment: For correct testing use `[price,ema_security1]= request.security(syminfo.tickerid,timeframe.period,[close,ta.ema(close,200)])`. There are too many tickers with name "SPY" from different exchanges. I suppose on the chart you have seen one "SPY", but the `security` have seen some other "SPY".

Comment: Perfect, ... Andrey, this was the problem!... everything works correcly now...

Comment: The other thing that was affecting the calculation was the the Dividend adjustment. the adj at the right bottom of the chart. if I have it selected and and is not specified at the reqeust.security the values are different.

Comment: y. The div adjustment, extended session hours and other things are "coded" in syminfo.tickerid